# (When) do screen reader users use tabs?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

TIL that screen reader users rarely use tabs for navigating web pages and instead use specific keyboard shortcuts from their screen reader software (e.g. *CTRL + OPTION + Arrow Keys* in VoiceOver). This would mean that optimizing for tabbable navigation does not always make sense.

However I've seen some web pages adding `tabindex="-1"` to their headline elements or for elements that are not directly viewable due to `overflow: scroll`.

So my question would be: When does it make sense to optimize for tab navigation and when doesn't it?

E.g. in our current use case we've created a questionnaire that basically shows a question (`h2` element) that can be answered with 2-5 answers (`button` elements). Clicking the answer will lead to a new page with the next question. When activating VoiceOver it seems like a good idea to have the question element set to `tabindex="-1"` and auto-focussed when the question is opened. But the learning above seems to challenge this a bit.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "But the learning above seems to challenge this a bit." ?

Comment: "When does it make sense to optimize for tab navigation and when doesn't it?" - Well, for one thing: when you're legally required to. Most countries have disability accessibility laws that require websites that are intended to be publicly accessible to be usable (and thus, navigable) by, for example, screen-readers - and there's more out there than just iOS VoiceOver. Have you tested with Android's screen reader, or with Lynx, JAWS and NVDA, for example?

Comment: @Dai: If screen reader users don't use tabs for navigating pages but their own screen reader's controls, it doesn't seem to make sense to optimize for tabbable navigation – and yes, we are aiming to create an accessible website independent from legal requirements, because we think that this should be the default today. Just asking what's the best way to do this.

Comment: "This would mean that optimizing for tabbable navigation does not always make sense." This is an incorrect conclusion. Accessibility is more than just screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

So first of all you are confusing tabbing with focus. While a screen reader user may use arrow key navigation, they may also bring up a list of links on the page, or forms, regions, tables or (most often) headings in order to navigate to sections that interest them / get a feel for the page layout.

Tabbing is useful as there are plenty of people who cannot, struggle or prefer not to use a mouse but do not require the assistance of a screen reader i.e. Cerebral Palsy due to accuracy issues.

Hopefully that clears that bit up for you.

As for autofocusing an input on a multi-page form, that is more of a UX issue...is it good UX for **all** users if you auto-focus the form.

I would say yes, requiring people to click, tab or use shortcuts to get to the input if that is going to be the action that 99% of people need to take is not good UX.

Notice I say the `<input>` and not the heading.

What you do want to do is look into how to indicate this is a multi-page and multi-step form on the first page of the process.

You should also consider having a checkbox as the first step that says something like "this form is multi-page, would you like us to auto-focus the first question when a new page is loaded" and have it default to checked.

That way someone has the *choice* to stop the auto focus if they wish.

Additionally (or as an alternative if you do not want the checkbox) you may consider adding some text near to the submit button (and properly associate it with `aria-labelledby` and an ID) that explains that the next step loads a new page and the first input will be auto focused.

Another thing is that assuming you have titled the pages correctly (Form name or process - step 2 of 5) then a screen reader user can easily ensure they are on the correct page.

So focus the input if this is a multi page form, not the heading level 1.

Focusing headings after navigation is a trick for Single Page Applications (SPAs) so that might be where you have seen that, if you load the page content via AJAX then that is one of the recommended ways to handle navigation. You indicated next page "loads" which makes me think this is a Multi Page Application, but I thought I better add that just in case as a general tip.

Bear in mind that all of this advice is general. Depending on your form, site design, loading pattern, user base (experienced users / internal system vs general public) etc. the best practice may be different.

So long answer short - use autofocus on the input if this is a multi step form and you think it is appropriate and obvious that the input would be the next thing to fill in.

Then **test it** with someone who uses a screen reader and get feedback as to whether it makes sense or if it was confusing or unexpected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think we have to clarify whether this should be a multi-step form with each question being a fieldset with radios being the answers or whether it's something else. We've decided not to use a form as we want the user to go see the next question after the previous one has been answered. This is why we are using a headline tag for the question and buttons for the answers. The question is more related to the latter.

Comment: As we currently don't have a form but are using a headline for the question and buttons for the answers: Does it make sense to auto-focus the question then? A form from our POV doesn't make sense as following answers might be different when previous answers are chosen. Using a form that would mean that we change the form's content while it's being filled out which doesn't seem very accessible.

Comment: It is still a form if you get the semantics right. If a Qn is single choice, style radio buttons to **look** like a button group. If it is multi choice, style some checkboxes to **look** like buttons. They key is to get the design you want while still enabling forms mode as it makes life much easier. As for forms where the answers depend on another, you don't need to do anything complicated, just hiding & unhiding the relevant fields is fine within a form, you only need to consider what happens if someone changes a previous answer (at which point a multi page form seems best to keep it clear!)

Comment: Think of the use case of a button, the expectation is that pressing a button will perform some action on the same page. So you would need to put work into indicating that button is pressed, that it has changed state etc. Going for native form elements that suite the question type will make life 100 times easier when trying to make things accessible. If you want to put a fiddle together that demos your form I can help you structure it and provide some hints on how to achieve a desired style while keeping the underlying HTML as simple and accessible as possible.

Comment: Alright, but what we don't like about this approach is that chosing an answer (e.g. selecting a radio option) would automatically step forward to the next question.

Comment: Okay, maybe using the form and having a checkbox that informs about auto-stepping as you said makes sense then…

Comment: Not necessarily, a form will only submit if you press a submit button or press Enter when not in a control. Just selecting a radio should have no action. Perhaps I have made it confusing, but for clarity a radio on its own in a form will do nothing, you need at least one `<button>` or some JS if you want it to submit on selecting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a confusion between **screen reader user** and **keyboard user**.
One doesn't necessarily implies the other.

People having dyslexia but normal sight may use a screen reader so that they can hear a text out loud instead of trying hard to read it themselves, but since they otherwise use a mouse or a touch interface, they aren't keyboard users.

People having difficulties using their hands but with a normal sight might not be able to use a mouse or a touch interface.
They don't need a screen reader, but use exclusively a keyboard or maybe another specific input device that mimique the most important keys of a keyboard (in particular, tab, arrow keys, enter and escape).
A joystick in some form can be such a device.

Considering what has been said above, designing a proper keyboard navigation and optimizing it always make sense. It may not be of important use for some screen reader users, but it's very important for keyboard users, as it's maybe their only way for them to interact with the app/page.

Answer (score 1):

I am a screen reader user.  With others, I believe a confusion about input focus is being associated with structural and contextual concerns.  To the first question regarding when to “optimize” TAB experiences.  It is always important since keyboard navigation  is a supporting pillar used in my toolbox as a screen reader user.  In addition, any input based non-screen reader accessibility tool is likely going to use this means of access.

As a developer, a guideline I always impress on other is the fact you want the natural structure and flow of code to do most of the work for you.  Secondly, the process should follow expectations of your target audience and it seems you want to follow a “wizard” style.  So, let me spell out a typical expectation for a wizard style questionnaire flow when using a screen reader.

UX point: does page reload fully or dynamically change?

This matters as this has a direct impact on my current reader “cursor” and how I will navigate to find the question.

From above statements, I will assume H2 will be used consistently. Thus, I will naturally use quick navigation to go to the first H2.

Now, I will use screen reader tools to read the question (be it TTS or braille output).

Once I feel I have its meaning, I will  typically use TAB to find the first input control.  Buttons are not input controls and thus violates user expectations.  I am looking for checkbox, radio box, text field, and/or combo box.

If check or radio boxes, then I am assuming a group and hope for grouping (sadly rarely present) and will use tactics to deal with the situation I have found.  If grouped, then I am using TABs a lot to move quickly and hear the “context” of the specific box focused with input.

Finally once I have answered the question,  I am looking for the next question or forward/previous mechanism.  These typically show up as buttons.

Hopefully, I am demonstrating how conventions/expectation are built using basic structure rather than trying to force procedure on the user.  Thirdly, sites like a11y project can be very helpful with coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the response I was hoping for. From your statements I assume that using grouped radio boxes with „previous“ and „next“ buttons would be the best solution to our wizard style use case. Also I assume that deciding for the user where the focus lays, generally is not a good idea. Probably also means that `aria-live` should be used very rarely. Hope I got that right. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is the general guidance I would give.  Indeed, messing with the focus can be quite problematic if all IX concerns are not considered.  As an example, imagine how frustrating it is for me to visit a page then navigate  to my POI just to have some JavaScript finally finish to move focus to the search field due to slow loading.  Now, I did mention dynamic page changes require additional efforts since I will not *know* changes happened which is when ARIA can be quite helpful with careful focus management but don’t think this applies to you.